# grep by special character ”

Tags: bash, grep, special-characters

How can I grep files with the special character `”` notice is different from `"`

I tried escaping it but wont work.

When I open the files with vim it appears as `<94>`

File example

```
<p>"hello”></p>
```

I want to be able to `grep -rne "\”"`

Comment: Please show us samples in your post, not clear from your post.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: So, you want to `grep` only `"` inside your file's content?

Comment: Yes, the curly " (different from normal ")

Comment: for me `grep "”" Input_file` is working fine for me, is it not working for you?

Comment: @kyodev That's a magnificently [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo)

Comment: Just `grep "”" Input_file` isnt working for me, maybe is a GNU shell issue I am having

Comment: @kyodev yes, that command displays LANG="es_ES.UTF-8"

Comment: Then the curly quote on your command line is a multi-byte UTF-8 sequence, not the byte 0x94. Maybe try `LC_ALL=C grep -rn $\x94'`

Comment: @kyodev, `grep ” <<<'<p>"hello”></p>'` -- no `echo` needed, and no command substitution.

Comment: Well, thank you, I had never tried :)@CharlesDuffy

Comment: @tripleee, ...I think you were missing a quote above, when entering `LC_ALL=C grep -rn $'\x94'`

Comment: Yup, the curses of mobile keyboards...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With modern GNU `grep` and properly configured locales, this should just work.

If your `grep` is not 8bit-savvy or your locales are hosed, maybe try e.g.

```
perl -ne 'print if /\x94/' files ...
```

It's not too hard to reimplement `grep -rn` in Perl but if this is a quick one-off, try

```
find . -type f -exec perl -ne 'print "$ARGV:$.:$_" if /\x94/' {} +
```

In some sense your locale *is* hosed or at least marginally nonstandard if `\x94` is displayed as a curly quote. Your system is apparently configured to use some legacy Windows 8-bit encoding...?

The curly quote isn't a shell or regex metacharacter so there should be no need to backslash it.

---

In some more details, based on comments, the fundamental problem is that your system is set up to use UTF-8 but the file uses a different encoding. So `grep "”"` really searches for the UTF-8 encoding of [U+201D](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201d/index.htm) which translates to `perl -ne 'print if /\xe2\x80\x9d/'`

If you don't know the byte value of the character, but you know the encoding, you can do

```
echo "”" | iconv -f utf-8 -t ENCODING | grep -f -
```

Of course, you can easily obtain the byte value by similar means;

```
echo "”" | iconv -f utf-8 -t ENCODING | xxd
```

or just view the file in a tool like `less` which shows unknown bytes in hex.

Maybe see also https://tripleee.github.io/8bit#9d -- with just a single byte, it doesn't matter which precise encoding the file is using (if it's HTML, the default in HTML 5 is, bewilderingly, Windows code page 1252) but if you have a few unknown bytes for which you know or can guess the expected rendering, this table can help you establish the precise encoding.

If your `grep` is not 8-bit savvy, maybe you are   using equipment from the Museum of Retrocomputing. If your locale is weird, maybe troubleshoot that - ideally you want [UTF-8 everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.com/).

Comment: My grep command isnt working however perl command worked, how can you display also with perl the file name?

Comment: The second example already does that. Just drop the `find` incantation in front if you don't need that.